# Redis server how to check pass value directly on value range

Tags: redis

I need to manage below data using redis.

```
Strat_range|End_range|circle|operator|operator_id|circle_id

918005000000|918005099999|UP EAST|BSNL|4|22
919967200000|919967299999|MAHARASHTRA|AIRTEL|15|20
```

I have one api for operator detection. I am passed mobile number via api & check number above series & which series match at configure & return line.

For example.
Mobile number :- 919967288367
This number match in second series. So that we return below out put.

```
919967200000|919967299999|MAHARASHTRA|AIRTEL|15|20
```

We need this match directly on value. because we not using loop for performance basis.

I have 10000 series.

Please help any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach is to use a Sorted Set, where members are your rows and their scores is the range's start.

E.g.:

```
ZADD ops 918005000000 "918005099999|UP EAST|BSNL|4|22" 919967200000 "919967299999|MAHARASHTRA|AIRTEL|15|20"
```

To query a number:

```
ZREVRANGEBYSCORE ops 919967288367 -inf LIMIT 0 1
```

Comment: when we increase LIMIT 0 5  for example :ZREVRANGEBYSCORE ops 919967288367 -inf LIMIT 0 5  , so that display both series.

Comment: @user3532146 I'm not sure I understand that.

Answer (score -1):

The solution is simple! **Store the series as keys instead as values**.

Details:
Store these series as Redis keys and values.

> **Key**: 918005000000 **Value**:918005099999|UP EAST|BSNL|4|22
>
> **Key**:919967200000 **Value**:919967299999|MAHARASHTRA|AIRTEL|15|20

Now, given a mobile number *919967288367*, form a key pattern like
`9199672*` and get all the matching keys.

From this set of keys select the smallest key and get it's value from redis.

Comment: That's a harmful anti pattern - getting keys based on their prefix isn't something you want to do in Redis because traversing the keyspace is an expensive operation.

Comment: Thank you for your insights. But since there are exactly 10000 series, getting keys based on prefix is not going to incur much of an overhead. Moreover, it's a known constant overhead, which is not harmful IMHO. Please do suggest any better alternatives instead of just down-voting.

Comment: I had actually suggested an alternative but regardless - recommending a full scan is a last resort solution, if at all.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Your solution is better